# $auth.login(..) from Satellizer returns $q deffered promise on error instead of resolved object

Tags: angularjs, satellizer

I'm using [Satellizer 0.15.5](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer), Webpack 2 and Angular 1.6.6
Using email/password authentication as described here: [Login with Email and Password](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer#-login-with-email-and-password)

When login successful, everything works fine and in resolve, I get the response with a token. When username/password is wrong, my reject callback doesn't being invoked and I get a $q object inside resolve, while I supposed to get resolved response from the server.

Code which I use:

```
$auth.login(credentials).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }, function (error) {
        console.error(error);
    })
```

Object which I get when username/password is wrong:

```
Deferred {promise: Promise, resolve: ƒ, reject: ƒ, notify: ƒ}
notify:ƒ (progress)
promise:Promise {$$state: {…}}
reject:ƒ (reason)
resolve:ƒ (val)
__proto__:Object
```

Will try to debug Satellizer, but maybe know the issue? In known issues in [Satellizer's repo](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/issues) I didn't find it. Satellizer library seen as abandoned so I asking this question here. Thank you for any help.

Comment: I've tried running their docs example https://github.com/sahat/satellizer but it seems with exactly same code as yours it yields either error 405 (Method Not Allowed) or 401, it's not returning promise object as what you're saying. So can you post more code of your loginController and the credentials object you're passing?

Comment: Thank you for your response, I can't share my code as is due to workplace limitation so I'll need to prepare plunker example especially for this case and will take a few days.